# Adding Custom property to common control issue

Tags: c#, interface, implementation

I'll like to know if there better way to implement Interface into a custom control.
I'm implementing a Interface in a custom button control, and  to refer to the implemented property I need to convert the Button to the interface type to reach it.

Is there a way to refer to it directly? Do I need to create a warper property in the button class, to expose it to outside world?

```
namespace WorkBench
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //Binding bind;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MyButton btn = new MyButton();
            btn.Myproperty = "";
            ((MyInterface)btn).MyProp = "";
            btn.MyProp = "Not Available";//This give compile error, MyProp not defined
        }


    }

    public class MyButton : System.Windows.Forms.Button, MyInterface
    {
        public string Myproperty
        {
            get { return null; }
            set { }
        }
        string MyInterface.MyProp
        { get { return null; } set { } }


    }

    public interface MyInterface
    {
        void MyOtherPropoerty();

        string MyProp
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're expecting the interface to store the value set. An interface is just a contract that the class must implement all of its members. Even if you comment out the line that is throwing an error you will get a compile-time error that your `MyButton` class doesn't implement all members of `MyInterface`.

You need to implement `string MyProp` on your `MyButton` class.

```
public class MyButton : System.Windows.Forms.Button, MyInterface
{
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return null; }
        set { /* ??? */ }
    }
    public string MyProp { get; set; } // <------ Implement string MyProp
}
```

However, if what you're actually trying to do is share a single property between multiple classes, you may consider using a base class instead:

```
public class MyControlBase
    : System.Windows.Forms.Button
{
    public string MyProp { get; set; }
}

public class MyButton : MyControlBase
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

--

```
void Example()
{
    var btn = new MyButton();
    var property = btn.MyProperty;
    var prop = btn.MyProp;
}
```

Comment: Sharing a single property between multiple classes, is what I wish to do. But for multiple type of Control, Combobox, Textbox, button, groupbox. That why I'm going with a Interface. But I'm facing the fact that the implemented property isn't accessible directly. (Your were right for the missing implementaion it was my error)